# spring+jsp app works in tomcat but respond 404 in embedded tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

I have a **spring-mvc + jsp** project that perfectly works on **external tomcat** server. I'm trying to make a **runable war** file with using **spring-boot and embedded tomcat** server. But when I try to call GET /student I recieve 404 error and no error message in console.

[project screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rEWT.png)

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
   UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
   resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
   resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
   resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
   return resolver;
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.4'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
id 'war'
}

description = 'Teaching Academy Web Application.'

ext.tomcatHome = 'D:/Soft/apache-tomcat-9.0.62'
ext.tomcatWebapps = "$tomcatHome/webapps"


war {
archiveName = 'academy-web.war' 
}

bootWar {
    archiveName = 'academy-web-bootable.war'
}

task deployToTomcat(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build'){    
    from war
    into "$tomcatWebapps"   
}

dependencies {
//  implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.3.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl'


    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    implementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17' 
    implementation "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior according to the development team of `Spring-boot`. The problem here is not the tomcat server if embedded or not, but the type of application that you deploy.

In external tomcat you package and deploy your application as `war` file, which `spring-boot` team has said that is able to support `jsp` pages.

In embedded tomcat probably you mean that you deploy your application as a standalone `.jar` file with an embedded server and here `spring-boot` team has mentioned that this is one of the limitations where `jsp` technology will not work. [Relevant Spring Boot documetation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.embedded-container.jsp-limitations)

Also checking closer your question you mention

> I'm trying to make a runable war file with using spring-boot and
> embedded tomcat server.

The embedded server will not work as expected with a `war` file. The `war` will contain `servlet` only information about the application, not the embedded server and not a standalone application that could start a server. So to sum up the `war` file when executed will not start a server and therefore the `404` response you get when you visit the application.